# PostGresql : Regex to select rows that have only one forward slash in them

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have some data with rows with data like

```
'abcd/12313:100', 
'abcd/12123:1001/XYS/ABCDXY',
'abcd/12123:1001/XYS/ABCDXY/TEYE'
```

I am trying to pick the rows that have one forward slash only using

```sql
select distinct id from public.table_name where id ~* '[/{0,1}]';

select distinct id from public.table_name where id ~* '/';
```

But I keep getting both rows back while I need to get only the first one (i.e :'abcd/12313:100')

I am running PostGresql 14.9.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression to match only those rows where exactly one forward slash appears in the `id` column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM public.table_name
WHERE LENGTH(id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(id, '/', '')) = 1;
```

`LENGTH(id)` gives you the original length of the string in the id column, and LENGTH(REPLACE(id, '/', '')) gives you the length of the string after all forward slashes have been removed. Subtracting the latter from the former will give you the number of forward slashes in the string

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a regular expression, you can match against:

```
^[^/]*/[^/]*$
```

which matches strings which have

- `^` : beginning of string
- `[^/]*` : some number of non-`/` characters
- `/` : a `/`
- `[^/]*` : some number of non-`/` characters
- `$` : end of string

In SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE id ~ '^[^/]*/[^/]*$'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ALKLOkCG)

However note using simple string operations such as the answer by @Manuvo would almost certainly be faster.

Comment: @Macky no worries. I think you've accepted the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would *say* it, the column contains *one slash, but not more*.

```
select * from t
where id like '%/%' and 
id not like '%/%/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

'[/{0,1}]' is matching any character between [, 0, ,, 1, and ], including the forward slash /. This is why you are getting all three rows in the result.

This is how to select rows that have only one forward slash:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM public.table_name WHERE id ~ '^[^/]*$';
```